# Purchasing Apple Mac Software: Options Available to the Consumer?

Tags: software-recommendation, mac-appstore, software

With regards to purchasing Apple Mac Software:

- Is the Majority of Software available for the Mac now available for purchase from the Mac App Store ? Are there Pros & Cons to Mac App Store purchasing ?
- Do people still purchase directly from the company website that created the software as an electronic download - I understand most companies offer a free trial (usually 30 days)
- Do people still buy "boxed software" from retail outlets and online retail stores ?

If the software is available via all these routes and maybe purchased in other ways, is there a recommended (instinctive) way or do people just go through the above options and see which turns out to be the cheapest ?

Thankyou

Comment: Yes, yes, yes and yes. You might want to limit down your question though so it actually addresses an issue or limitation you are running into, and it can be properly answered.

Comment: The only issue I have is which do most people do ? Example you are an experienced Apple User who buys software from time to time, which steps do you automatically do?

Comment: I have only used Freeware, but there must be people who purchase on a regular basis and therefore be able to provide tips (if i'm making sense)

Comment: Actually I don't think the question does make any sense, unless you are collecting info for some kind magazine piece. I would expect you to ask something more like "I need to buy MS Office for Mac -- Where do you think is the best place for me to do that?"

Comment: @Tom Gewecke: In terms of buying MS Office for Mac...do you go straight to the Mac App Store, do you go to Amazon or PC World (if these stores are available in your country) or do you go straight to the Microsoft website..and see which is cheapest ?

Comment: Should I walk into an Apple Store, and buy the software there

Comment: @Tom Gewecke: The question made perfect sense to daGUY, who gave a comprehensive answer

Comment: For Office Amazon looks good to me, $90 at the moment.  Yes, find the cheapest place.

Comment: @Tom Gewecke: Thats the whole point of my question, to find the best way to purchase software (hopefully at the cheapest price). daGUY  even mentioned the biggest pro of the Mac App Store is being able to install software on up to 5 Macs (I would have never known that, unless he stated it). Well done daGUY on what I hope is a valuable question and answer to everyone. Anyone else like to add to daGUY's comprehensive and informative answer is very welcomed

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful.  I find it pretty useless and unworthy of this kind of forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the Majority of Software available for the Mac now available for
>   purchase from the Mac App Store ? Are there Pros & Cons to Mac App
>   Store purchasing?

I don't know exactly how you would compile those numbers, or if Apple even releases numbers for the Mac App Store, so it's difficult to say how the "majority" is sold.

As for pros and cons, probably the biggest pro is Mac App Store purchases can be used on any number of Macs that you own (see [Apple's FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4461)); you don't need to buy additional licenses for each machine as long as it's for personal use. Also, updates are delivered through the store, so you get a notification when updates are available.

Installing from the Mac App Store is also presumably more secure because Apple has tested and approved all apps before making them available (and can revoke an app developer's certificate, which is a benefit assuming a rogue app sneaks through, but could also be a negative if they abuse that ability).

> Do people still purchase directly from the company website that
>   created the software as an electronic download - I understand most
>   companies offer a free trial (usually 30 days)

Well, sure, why not? There's no requirement that all apps have to go through the Mac App Store. However, the Mac App Store does not offer trials, so you'll need to purchase directly from the developer if you want a trial (assuming they offer one).

> Do people still buy "boxed software" from retail outlets and online
>   retail stores ?

Again, sure, of course you can if you want.

> If the software is available via all these routes and maybe purchased
>   in other ways, is there a recommended (instinctive) way or do people
>   just go through the above options and see which turns out to be the
>   cheapest?

I'd say the Mac App Store is the easiest and most straightforward option for most users, since it's integrated right into OS X and updates are delivered automatically.

Comment: Thankyou so much for giving quite a comprehensive answer and even informing me that the Mac App Store would not permit a free trial (which might be disadvantageous), compared to buying direct online. I hope new Apple users find this information as useful as I have and will bear this in mind on future purchases of Mac Software. Excellent

Comment: @Simon: I was wrong – there's actually no limit to the number of machines you can install a Mac App Store purchase on, as long as it's for personal use.

Comment: Thankyou, I'm relatively new to Mac, and dont spend alot of time on it. Any question I ask, i'm asking not to be funny, but because I'd like to know the best solution. As you can see this question has now been closed